# Executing directory

Tags: c#, directory

I have a C# program that is running and I want to launch another executable in different directory.

I have this code on event:

```
 string path = "Y:\Program\test.exe";
 Process.Start(path);
```

Problem is that in order for program to work right it need to take information from settings.ini where the exe file is located but it takes settings.ini from program folder with which I am trying to launch second program. test.exe is working fine when I am opening it from its folder by double click. What could be the problem?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the process what the working directory is via [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = @"Y:\Program",
    FileName = @"Y:\Program\test.exe",
};

Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

**Edit:**

In order to get the directory from the user, you can use `DirectoryInfo.FullName`:

```
var userFileInfo = new FileInfo(userInsertedVariableHere);
var parentDirectory = userFileInfo.Directory.FullName;
```

Comment: I need it to work with any directory user writes in. Im saving it in path so question is if user writes path Y:\Program\test.exe How can I trim end of it so it becomes Y:\Program ?